# Laravel eloquent relationships not working

Tags: php, laravel, orm, foreign-keys

I have two tables as `users` and `notifications`, and I have a foreign key of `notification_id` in my `users` table, and in `notifications.blade.php`, I'm trying to get the user through `id` of `notifications` table as:

**NotificationController:**

```
public function notifications() {
    $notifications = App\Notification::latest('created_at')->get();
    return view('notifications', compact('notifications'));
}
```

**notifications.blade.php:**

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    {{ $notification->user->id }}
@endforeach
```

**User.php(model):**

```
public function notifications() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Notifications', 'notification_id');
}
```

**Notification.php(model):**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'notification_id');
}
```

**Notifications table schema:**

```
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('message');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Users table schema:**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->unsignedInteger('notification_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('notification_id')->references('id')->on('notifications');
});
```

but I'm getting **Trying to get property of non-object** error.

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\WampServer\www\DigitalInvigilator\resources\views\admin\notifications.blade.php)`

Comment: if notifications `belongsTo` a user, I believe you should have your foreign key on your notifications table as "user_id". you could try `dd($notifications)` to see what the controller is trying to return.

Comment: @TJWeems I have the `notification_id` as a foreign key in my `users` table

Comment: try `dd($notifications)` to see what `$notifications` is returning

Comment: It's showing all notifications.

Comment: The method name in Notification.php appears to be `users`, but you're calling `user` in your blade file. If it's a singular relationship, change the method name in your model

Comment: @ChrisForrence typo mistake, checked with both but not working

Comment: Hmm. Would you mind posting your database schemas for those two tables? It sounds like according to your database definition from earlier comments, a user can only have a single notification.

Comment: @ChrisForrence yes a user have only 1 notifcation, let me post my db schemas.

Comment: So while this won't fix this specific issue, that's going to be an issue with a hasMany relationship on your User (since that implies that a user has many notifications); will wait for the schemas

Comment: @ChrisForrence chk I have updated

Comment: Yep. Basically, with your database definition, a notification is essentially the parent record of a user, so your User model would have a belongsTo relationship with Notification, while your Notification model would have a hasMany relationship with User.

Comment: @ChrisForrence answer it and I will execpt, thankssssssssssss

Comment: 1 Question that there's only one to one relationship b\w these two, but if I write `hasOne`, it gives error, otherwise by using `hasMany`, it won't give error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, thanks to **Chris Forrence**, I have changed the relation-ship as **Chris Forrence** said.

Answer (score 1):

the foreign key must be in `Notification` model (`user_id`) instead `User` model.
because your relationship say that

**EDIT:**

your code must be like this:
User.php(model):

```
public function notifications() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Notification', 'user_id');
}
```

Notification.php(model):

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Notifications table schema:

```
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('message');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
});
```

Users table schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
});
```

Comment: I can't change the foreign key, can you make relationship for my existing code? as `notification_id` foreign key

Comment: No. You can not do rhat you want whitout  changue tje tables. Because the relationship that you want to use is a one (user) to many(norification)  and this meaning that  your foreign key MUST be in your "many side" model(notification)